wp_get_attachment_image_src not returning and image on some posts(videos)
wp_get_attachment_image_src not returning and image on some posts(videos)in Wordpress.
I have a bookmarks section on my website so you can bookmark/save your favorite videos. The manually uploaded videos thumbnails are not being displayed in the users bookmarked list but all embedded videos are displaying there thumbnails in the users list as normal. is there a reason this might be? I need the manually uploaded videos to have there thumbnails display properly. thank you, any help is appreciated.
The plugin i am using is using the following code:
/**
 * Template for displaying a bookmarks list
 *
 * Used:  Profile page > Bookmarks tab > All
 * Call:  UM()->User_Bookmarks()->profile()->get_user_profile_bookmarks_all();
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/ultimate-member/um-user-bookmarks/profile/bookmarks.php
 *
 * @see      https://docs.ultimatemember.com/article/1516-templates-map
 * @package  um_ext\um_user_bookmarks\templates
 * @version  2.0.7
 *
 * @var  array  $bookmarks
 */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}
?>

<div class="um-user-bookmarked-list">
    <?php
    foreach ( $bookmarks as $post_id ) {
        $bookmarked_post = get_post( $post_id );
        if ( empty( $bookmarked_post ) || is_wp_error( $bookmarked_post ) ) {
            continue;
        }

        if ( ! post_type_exists( $bookmarked_post->post_type ) ) {
            continue;
        }

        $has_image       = false;
        $has_image_class = 'no-image';
        $image           = [];
        $image_url       = '';
        if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post_id ) ) {
            $has_image       = true;
            $has_image_class = 'has-image';
            $image           = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id ), 'thumbnail' );
            $image_url       = $image[0];
        }
        $content = '';
        if ( $bookmarked_post->post_content ) {
            $content .= strip_shortcodes( $bookmarked_post->post_content );
            $content = str_replace( ']]>', ']]&gt;', apply_filters( 'the_content', $content ) );
        }

        UM()->get_template( 'profile/single-folder/bookmark-item.php', um_user_bookmarks_plugin, array(
            'excerpt'           => trim( substr( strip_tags( $content ), 0, 130 ) ),
            'has_image'         => $has_image,
            'has_image_class'   => $has_image_class,
            'id'                => $post_id,
            'image'             => $image,
            'image_url'         => $image_url,
            'post_link'         => get_the_permalink( $post_id ),
            'post_title'        => get_the_title( $post_id ),
            'user_id'           => $user_id,
        ), true );
    }
    ?>
    <div class="um-clear"></div>
</div>```

